# Extend gradient to two separate areas

Tags: gradient, adobe-flash

I have two open areas in a picture which aren't connected, but I want the same gradient to be present in both of their backgrounds. Is there any way to achieve this with the same gradient? If it helps, they're the same color without the gradient. Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you have any example image please post for exact answer..

Comment: you can copy first area gradient and paste it for 2nd one and use it.its what i understood with this question

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible with the same gradient, as stated. I know that a gradient remains in two spots even after a line has been drawn through it, and was wondering if it would be possible to have a gradient extended to another spot similarly, after it has been separated.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done in Flash, which is the software mentioned in your tags (you should have mentioned this in your question text as well.) You can just use the eyedropper to pick up the gradient from one area and fill the other area with it. The trick is that you will probably have to use the Gradient Transform tool (it's found by clicking and holding on the Transform tool) in order to make the gradient extend to both areas.

Comment: I would just add, once you move one of the shapes, the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Flash, But I do know that if I wanted to do something like this in Illustrator or Photoshop, I might create a layer with a gradient, and then apply a `layer mask` to it.

Comment: That is the best way to accomplish this in Photoshop definitely: apply the gradient, then split the pieces apart. Flash however maintains a linkage between the two pieces.

Comment: I would probably keep the pieces as copies and then group duplicates to form the mask.